# Yaw angle of lse_xsens_mti behaves weirdly

Tags: ros, imu, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the [lse_xsens_mti](http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_xsens_mti) driver on my robot . I  had it turn 360 degrees at a uniform velocity, and computed the Yaw angle output by the driver data in two ways:

1. Using the  `tf::getYaw()`   function on the quat formed by the orientation.x,y,z,w values output by imu/data.
2. By `atan2(w,z)*2`  on the z and w values.

In both cases, the Yaw angle didn't vary uniformly with time as the robot turned. What could be wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11793/yaw-angle-of-lse_xsens_mti-behaves-weirdly/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-03-13**:
The lse_xsens_mti driver did not see much testing since it was created, I will take a look at it and update it soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there was a bug on MTi.h discovered by Prof. Dr. Stefan May which as already been corrected. Could you please verify that the software now works as expected?

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1